# How to implement user authentication in a jsp web application, using a glassfish JDBC Realm?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish, jdbcrealm

We have been attempting to create user logins on our JSP web app using JDBC realms, following [this tutorial](http://jugojava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html). We have followed the tutorial like for like, but it just won't work! Basically, the login form doesn't accept any credentials, however we don't know if it's due to a communication issue, or that there is no communication!

Here is some of our code, which hopefully is enough to show what went wrong!

Our relevant database tables:

[image: database tables]

Our web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>JSP configuration for Bandy</description>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>            
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/menu.jspf</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/seal.jspf</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>    
</jsp-config>     
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>bandyRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>       
</login-config>        
<security-constraint>        
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Bandy user</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/protected.jsp</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>        
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Our glassfish-web.xml file:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
<class-loader delegate="true"/>
<jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
        <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
</jsp-config>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>USER</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

Our jdbc realm settings:

[image: jdbc realm]

Our project structure:

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declared realm in web.xml (bandyRealm) doesn't exist.  Try setting it to what you named in glassfish, namely "jdbc-realm"